# Sorts and constructors for modelling classes in a theorem prover

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving

I have been working in the [Welder](https://github.com/epfl-lara/welder/) theorem prover for some time now. But I'm confused in the way they handle data-types. I'm not familiar with the terminology of sorts and constructors. Here is how one defines a list data-type in the system:

```
val list = mkSort("A")(Seq(cons, nil))
val nil = mkConstructor("A")(Some(list))(_ => Seq())
val cons = mkConstructor("A")(Some(list)) { case Seq(aT) =>
  Seq((head, aT), (tail, list(aT)))
}
```

So essentially one defines a `sort` for the abstract class `list` and then instantiates this sort with concrete classes or constructors. My question is where does this terminology come from?

To finish, would you have an idea how can I model a mathematical field using this notation? I tried:

```
  val element = mkSort(Seq(zero, one, notZeroOne))
  val zero = mkConstructor(Some(element)) {_ => Seq()}
  val oneADT = mkConstructor(oneID)()(Some(element)) {_ => Seq()}
  val notZeroOneADT = mkConstructor(Some(element)) {_ => Seq()}
```

But this says that an element has zero, one or a non-zero and not-one element. Someone suggested me to use a natural index as identifier but this would limit me to countable fields.